# How to represent XMLGregorianCalendar in protobuf 3 format

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have an xml with time as

```
<Opened date="2012-09-13T18:30:34+05:30" Lang_Code="ENG"></Opened>
```

I need to represent it in proto3 format and ship the generated java classes.
what data type to use? I tried  google.protobuf.Timestamp but that does not fit the bill.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Opened{

  <what data type?> date =1;

  string lang_code=2;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to at least *consider* using the `DateTime` message in [google/type/datetime.proto](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/type/datetime.proto) - that repo is the one we (Google) use for our public API protos, including supporting types like `DateTime`.

You'd probably want to document and validate that:

- The `year` value would never be 0
- The `hour` value would never be 24
- The `seconds` value would never be 60 (unless you actually plan on supporting leap seconds)
- The `time_offset` oneof will always be populated via `utc_offset`

Of course, you can create your own proto with similar information, should you wish. There's no out-of-the-box message that includes what you need, so you'll need to use *some* kind of message, unless you want to just leave it as a string (which I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: Will this require anything extra? 
The import `import "google/type/datetime.proto";`
is not available out of the box.. maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: @KoustavRay: Well you'd need to either clone that repo, or at least copy the proto definition, so that it's available to protoc. The proto compiler doesn't know to fetch from GitHub itself. You could then either generate it yourself, or depend on the Maven package that includes the generated code. (I'm afraid I don't know which package that is offhand.)

Comment: I am afraid such a custom solution might not be acceptable for us in our organization. thanks though

Comment: @KoustavRay: It's less of a custom solution than creating your own similar proto, which is the other thing I'd suggest. Basically there are no "well-known" types in protobuf that pass along the information you want. So unless you decide to just specify it as a string, you'll need a message like this *somewhere*. You can create your own, or you can use the one we've already provided in google.type.

Comment: Thanks @Jon using a custom one now cloned from the type you provided.